# Facebook Social Plugin - The endpoint used to load this resource has been deprecated

Tags: facebook-like, deprecated, facebook-social-plugins, app-id

not sure but seems I've read this is the unofficial forum to use for Facebook developer questions (and no doubt the source for many solutions in general).

I've recently tried to add a like and comment plugin to the end of my articles on an online newspaper, however, nothing shows up on any browser. I created it as an app (for app id purposes) and created a page for said app.

I've generated the code via this link ( https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins ).

Like button example: 
added the API call just below the body tag...

```
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
...
```

and the required html tags...

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://mywebsite.com/article.php?num=<? echo $number; ?>" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
```

I get the following errors via chrome's console...

```
1)The endpoint used to load this resource has been deprecated.
Please update to the current Facebook JavaScript SDK.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/
FB.Share:53
2)  Invalid App Id: Must be a number or numeric string representing the application id. FB.Share:53
3)  The "fb-root" div has not been created, auto-creating FB.Share:53
4)  FB.getLoginStatus() called before calling FB.init().
```

Any ideas as to why this is happening would be great. I can provide a live link, but preferably only if necessary.

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not a forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/is-stack-overflow-a-forum). Also, did you read the error? Have you updated?

Comment: I'm sorry, should have been more avid in my word choice.
Not sure what I could update. I simply copied the provided code generated from the link above. Are there some other elements I need to look into on my end? Is it possible some other framework (such as jquery) is interfering?

Comment: I've run the URL through https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ and added the following lines of code '<meta property="og:title" content="TITLE" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://mywebsite.com/img/layout/image.jpg" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://mywebsite.com/" />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="SITE NAME" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="SITE DESC" />
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" />'

Still the same results and no more warnings/errors

Comment: If you feel that it will benefit future users, consider posting your own answer to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the old method I was using stopped all calls to the Facebook API. The following line was the culprit...

```
<script src="static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share"; type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: How to replace above line? Which link you have used ?